# why usestate prints in a different order

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

why doesnt this go sequentially like the first run 1a>1b>2a>2b

also why does prevstate changes in 2b even though new render hasnt happened?
I'm new to react and having very hard time understanding all these

```
 const [vald, setVald] = useState("d");

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("1a",vald)
    setVald(prevstate=>(
      console.log("1b",prevstate),
      "d1"
      ))
  },[vald])
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("2a",vald)
    setVald(prevstate=>(
      console.log("2b",prevstate),
      "d2"
      ))
  },[vald])
  console.log("render")
```

the output is

```
render
1a d 
1b d 
2a d 
2b d1
render
1a d2 
2a d2 
1b d2 
2b d1
render
```

Comment: setState is not synchronous

Comment: @hellogoodnight I don't think that completely answers the question though; why the sequence of outputs is different in first and second runs. My guess the explanation is somewhere in the event loop.

Comment: I'm aware setState is asynchronous but why does the order change?
Also if its asynchrounous truly its order should be 1a>2a>1b>2b but that doesnt happen in first instance and why doesnt `setVald("d1")` doesnt trigger rerender immediately? but changes value in 2b in first run?